# Firebase 3 auth via slug?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement my database rules on my firebase database.

for now I have:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "(auth != null) && !root.child('users/'+ newData.child('slug').val()).exists()",
      "$username": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false,
        "clubs": {
          ".read": "(auth != null)",
          ".write": false
        },
        "roles": {
          ".read": "(auth != null)",
          ".write": false
        }
      }
    },
    "clubs": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

and the data looks like following:

```
{
    clubs: {
        smash_for_fun: {
            description: "The best club ever!",
            name: "Smash For Fun",
            slug: "smash_for_fun",
            users: {
                glenn_lastname: true
            }
        }
    },
    users: {
        glenn_lastname: {
            clubs: {
                smash_for_fun: true
            },
            name: "Glenn Lastname",
            slug: "glenn_lastname",
            uid: "edtJDkUnEOXAUnl0J9GfXIsOqgG2"
        },
        other_user: {
            name: "Other user",
            slug: "other_user",
            uid: "sgsdkjfnsdfnsdkjfnlsdfndsjfn"
        }
    }
}
```

but how can i make the rules so a user can only write his own details, but not from a other user?

and how to check if the user.slug doesn't exists?

Comment: This is invalid syntax `newData.slug`. You're probably looking for `newData.child('slug')`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you are correct, changed that :)